# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set of subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Assume that $\mathscr{C}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $|\mathscr{C}|=n.$ Show that $|\sigma(\mathscr{C})|\leq 2^{2^n}.$ Where $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{C}$.

I'm trying to do this by first looking at the special case that all the sets in $\mathscr{C}$ are disjoint and cover $\Omega$. My idea was that in this case I can write any element of $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$ as some combination of sets in $\mathscr{C}$ in a way that makes the number of said combinations easy to count. However, I am having trouble with this approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $k$ pairwise disjoint nonempty sets, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets contains  $2^k$ sets.

Let $\mathcal C = \{C_1,\ldots,C_n\}$. Let $\mathcal D$ be the collection of all sets of the form $$D_1 \cap D_2 \cap \cdots \cap D_n$$ where each $D_k$ is either $C_k$ or $C_k^c$. There are at most $2^n$ such sets since some of the intersections could be empty, and they are pairwise disjoint.  Every set in $\mathcal C$ can be written as a union of sets in $\mathcal D$ so that $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \sigma(\mathcal D)$, and the number of sets in $\sigma(\mathcal D)$ equals $2^{|\mathcal D|} \le 2^{2^n}$.

Comment: I have seen a number of approaches like this. What I do not quite understand is why $|\sigma (\mathcal D)| = 2^{|\mathcal D|}$. Could you explain or give a source for this please?

Comment: Actually I believe I have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Umberto P.'s answer is what led me to this answer, I would just like to type up a complete answer for myself.

Suppose that $\mathscr{C}={C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n}$ where the $C_i$ are pairwise disjoint and $\cup_{i=1}^n C_i = \Omega$. Now note any intersection of sets from $\mathscr{C}$ is equal to $\varnothing$. Also $C_i^c=\cup_{j\neq i} C_j.$ So any set in $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$ is of the form $\cup_{i=1}^n C_i'$, where $C_i'=C_i, \text{or} \ \varnothing$. There are $2^n$ such sets and so $|\sigma(\mathscr{C})|=2^n<2^{2^n}$.

In the general case proceed in the manner of Umberto P.'s answer.